# Extracting specific features using expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, extract, definition-query, integer

I have a field holding strings like this - `1,2,3,4,5,11,12,10` (each record contains a combination of figures from 1 to 20 separated by commas).

I need to extract only the records containing in this field (named `"Cod_niv"`) values `< 9`. I have tried to use `"Cod_Niv" LIKE '%1,%' Or "Cod_Niv" LIKE '%2,%'`  but it returned not only records containing 1 and 2 but also 11, 12 etc. I would need to obtain only records containing figures from 1 to 9.

Comment: What software do you use?

Comment: I guess it is QGIS.

Comment: I think it's ArcMap but we need the asker to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Open the "Select Features by Expression" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) window. Use the following expression:

```sql
with_variable(
    'list',
    -- convert string to list
    string_to_array("Cod_niv", delimiter:=','),

    array_length(
        array_filter(
            @list,
            @element < 9  -- comparison
        )
    -- if @list length equals the list length returning from 
    -- expression above, the feature is selected
    ) = array_length(@list)
)
```

[image]